# for loop: Select users that have used specific words more than x times in R

Tags: r, for-loop, text, nlp

I have a dataframe (df) with user_names and text for each user. I have another data_frame with important words. I want to create a for loop that iterates over each user and counts how often the important words appear in their text.

**Data:**

```
important_words = c("marcus", "yesterday", "democrat", "republican", "trump", "hillary")

df$user_names 
[1] "marc12"
[2] "jon"
[3] "67han"
[4] "XXmark"
[5] "mark"
[6] "mark"

df$text
[1] "hi my name is marcus and i am a republican"
[2] "i support hillary"
[3] "go trump!"
[4] "tomorrow i will vote democrat"
[5] "i don't think so"
[6] "yesterday was ok"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract all the `important_words` for each `user_names` and count number of unique important words each user has.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(user_names) %>%
  summarise(unique_imp_word = n_distinct(unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(text),
                str_c('\\b', tolower(important_words), '\\b', collapse = "|")))))
```

Comment: How would I do that in a for loop, if let's say I had 150 users?

Comment: Doesn't matter. `str_count` is vectorized it would work for all `df$text` at once.

Comment: @AnaWilmer Do you have multiple rows for each user and you want to count number of important words for each user? Do you want to count only occurrence of unique `important` words ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!

Comment: Ana, if you find yourself thinking "I need to write a loop in R", you are almost certainly working inefficiently.  There are a few exceptions, but this is a good working assumption.